# curl.exe does not append file body

Tags: curl

I am executing the following curl command on windows. The command is executed but curl does not append the file body. It only writes the headers:

```
curl.exe -H "Authorization: Bearer very-secret-stuff" -F file=@E:/almostEmpty.txt --verbose https://to-this-address
```

**Sent Request:**

```
POST /api/rest/v5/transientDocuments HTTP/1.1
Host: api.eu1.echosign.com
User-Agent: curl/7.56.1
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer very-secret-stuff
Content-Length: 214
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------e84a74f3e81c968e

***Nothing here. The file body is actually missing***
```

**Received Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 08 Nov 2017 12:28:00 GMT
Server: Apache
x-request-id: 613647cc-c04b-49d7-8b86-62fc65841a8a
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Content-Length: 61
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Robots-Tag: none
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{"code":"NO_FILE_CONTENT","message":"Must provide file body"}

Closing connection 0
TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Comment: file=@E:/almostEmpty.txt: shouldn't it be a backslash " \"?

Comment: Tried already all combinations: 
file=@E:\almostEmpty.txt 
file=@E:\\almostEmpty.txt
always the same outcome

Comment: Putting it between ""?

Comment: Nope. Done already
-F "file=@E:\almostEmpty.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their [documentation](https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/sign/docs/developer-guide/using-http/send-for-signing.html), the parameter for the document is `File`, not `file`.

Try changing your cURL command to use:

```
-F File=@E:/almostEmpty.txt
```

Also note that `--verbose` won't display the file content on the console, just the headers and response headers.  Your file was being sent, just with the wrong form parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW:
ContentType *without* a hyphen

And as Drew says above "File" post field with capital F